# I have 2 kustomization overlays that call the same configuration. I need to have two kustomization.yaml files in the same folder

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

```
overlays -----> configuration1 ----> kustomization.yaml 
         |   
         |----> configuration2 ----> kustomization.yaml
```

```
resources ------> kustomization.yaml

# in file resources/kustomization.yaml
# for configuration1 
resources:
  - pvc.yaml
  - deployment.yaml
  - namespace.yaml

# for configuration2
resources:
  - pvc.yaml
  - network.yaml
  - istio.yaml
```

end goal

```
kubectl apply -k overlays/configuration1
kubectl apply -k overlays/configuration2
```

I have an overlays folder that contains two folders. configuration1 and configuration2. In those folders I have a kustomization.yaml file. These two kustomization files call the same resource folder. configuration1 and configuration2 need to have a different list of resources specified. Can I create two different kustomize.yaml files in the resource folder or is there anyway to specify two different list of resources in the same kustomization.yaml?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking for. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HelloWorld I added "end goal". See above.

Comment: Share the contents of your `configuration1/kustomization.yaml` & `configuration2/kustomization.yaml`. And still your question is unclear on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would use the following structure:

```
base/
  kustomization.yaml
  pvc.yaml
overlays/
  configuration1/
    kustomization.yaml
    deployment.yaml
    namespace.yaml
  configuration2/
    kustomization.yaml
    network.yaml
    istio.yaml
```

`base/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - pvc.yaml
```

`overlays/configuration1/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../../base
  - namespace.yaml
  - deployment.yaml
```

`overlays/configuration2/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../../base
  - network.yaml
  - istio.yaml
```

The idea is to keep in the base the configuration that is common to both and move to each overlay the configuration specific to it.